# Print Objects of a specific type but stored using a different constructor

Tags: java, eclipse

I seem to be a little stuck and haven't been able to look for a solution online. All and any pointers to other threads and feedback are welcome.

Below is the class with multiple constructors;

```
public class Rating
{
  public long userId, movieId, timestamp;
  public Integer rating;
  public double averageRating;

  public Rating(long userId, long movieId, Integer rating, long timestamp)
  {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.movieId = movieId;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
  }

  public Rating(long userId, long movieId, int rating)
  {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.movieId = movieId;
    this.rating = rating;
  }

  public Rating(long movieId, double averageRating)
  {
    this.movieId = movieId;
    this.averageRating = averageRating;
  }
...
```

Below is the attempted implementation of the third Rating constructor;

```
public List<Rating> getTopTenMovies()
{
    comparator = new RatingByRatingComparator(); //Sorts averageRating in descending order
    List<Rating> topTen = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Movie movie: movies.values())
    {
        long movieId = movie.movieId;
        double averageRating = movie.getAverageRating();
        Rating rating = new Rating(movieId, averageRating);
        topTen.add(rating);
    }
    Collections.sort(topTen, comparator);

    if (topTen.size() > 10)
    {
        return topTen.subList(0, 9);
    }
    else
    {
        return topTen;
    }
}
```

When I print the returned List from the getTopTenMovies() method, I get this;

```
[Rating{0, 1, null, 0}, Rating{0, 8, null, 0}, Rating{0, 2, null, 0}, Rating{0, 3, null, 0}, ... etc]
```

From the above, I'm guessing the default(?) constructor for Rating is being used.

I would like to print them in the same format(Rating{1, 4.0}) as which I saved them to the ArrayList using a specific constructor.

Also, would you suggest using a separate class instead of trying to make do with an extra constructor in the Rating class.

Many thanks and apologies for usage of wrong terminology or anything. All feedback is valued greatly.

Matt

Comment: When you say "I'm guessing the default(?) constructor for Rating is being used" it makes me think you don't fully understand certain concepts because 1) in general you can't reliably tell which constructor was used to create an object based upon the object's String representation (unless the code explicitly tracks the constructor that was used - which would be unusual) and 2) a default constructor is one that takes no parameters and is provided automatically by the compiler. Please see [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: @D.B. Thank you, I was rather confused

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing the default(?) constructor for Rating is being used

Because you are passing `long` and `double` arguments the constructor with `Rating(long movieId, double averageRating)` will be invoked.

> I would like to print them in the same format(Rating{1, 4.0})

If you want to format the `Rating` (list) output to be displayed, you need to override `toString()` in your `Rating` class as shown below:

```
public class Rating {

   //add existing code here

    public String toString() {
            return novieId + "," + averageRating;
    }
 }
```